# invalid identifier oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Hello I need someone tell me why oracle keeps giving me this message

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 670
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 656
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1768


4.     SLSREP_LAST char(10) not null,
5.     SLSREP_FIRST char(10) not null,
6.     GENDER char(1) not null check(GENDER in('F','M')),
7.     STREET char(15) not null,
8.     CITY char(15) not null,
```

Here is what I made to get this message:

```
 create table SALES_REP
(
    SLSREP_NUMBER char(2) primary key,
    SLSREP_LAST char(10) not null,
    SLSREP_FIRST char(10) not null,
    GENDER char(1) not null check(GENDER in('F','M')),
    STREET char(15) not null,
    CITY char(15) not null,
    SLSREP_STATE char(2) not null,
    ZIP_CODE char(5) not null,
    TOTAL_COMMISSION decimal(7,2) not null,
    COMMISSION_RATE decimal(3,2) not null,
)
```

Im still learning how to do sql and I dont know how to fix this

Comment: remove the last comma before the close parenthesis

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using `char()` is pretty much always the wrong choice

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Developper GUI for example to create tables ? It's much much faster than typing the code of each table. except if you need to create tables automatically...